# refactor ReactJS component to remove getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following React component which is working as desired.  After reading about fully controlled components in [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component) blog post I'm wondering if this code could be refactored to make it fully controlled, which could eliminate the use of `getDerivedStateFromProps`, if I understand correctly.  Being more familiar with Vue Native than React Native I'm looking for some guidance on how to go about doing such a refactor.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Content, Picker } from "native-base";

export default class DynamicPicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: this.props.selected
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.selected !== prevState.selected) {
      return ({ selected: nextProps.selected });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  onValueChange(value) {
    this.setState({
      selected: value
    });
    this.props.onValueChange(value);
  }

  itemsList = () => {
    return (this.props.items.map( (item, index) => {
      return (<Picker.Item label={item} key={index} value={item} />)
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
            <Picker
              // note
              mode="dropdown"
              style={{ borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, height: 40, margin: 5 }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selected}
              onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
            >
              { this.itemsList() }
            </Picker>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing you actually don't need any state here or the method `onValueChange`.

Why do you want to get a value from props just to set it on the state? Can't you just use the `selected` value received as props?

Also, can't you just use the method `onValueChange` received from props? I don't see any need to make another one in this component, because you're setting a new state, but you're going to change the state after that because you call `this.props.onValueChange`. When any prop changes the component will rerender, therefore `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be called and it will modify the state.

Long story short, this is how I see this component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Content, Picker } from "native-base";

export default class DynamicPicker extends Component {      
  itemsList = () => 
  // Implicit return from the arrow function  
  this.props.items.map( (item, index) => {
      return (<Picker.Item label={item} key={index} value={item} />)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
            <Picker
              // note
              mode="dropdown"
              style={{ borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, height: 40, margin: 5 }}
              selectedValue={this.props.selected}
              onValueChange={this.props.onValueChange}
            >
              { this.itemsList() }
            </Picker>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hit a bump with changing `selectedValue={this.props.selected}`; this error appeared: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.selected').  Got any ideas about why it wouldn't like that?

Comment: Are you still using anywhere in that component `this.state.selected`? If you removed the state but you kept `getDerivedStateFromProps` can be the reason. I can't really pronounce if I don't know exactly how your component looks right now.

Comment: I must've pasted something wrong initially - that error has disappeared now.  However, no values are being displayed in the drop down boxes.

Comment: @knot22, have  you found the problem? This component seems to look good from my perspective, but I may miss something.

Comment: I tried setting up a sandbox to demonstrate its behavior but got stuck on an error message related to a react-native dependency.  This is as far as the demo got... https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-picker-tww2x
Some parts of the example are missing on account of getting stuck.  If you know how to get the dependency resolved, let me know and I will complete the example.